# In what year is Layer Cake set?

Tags: layer-cake

Layer Cake was released in 2004.  There is a lot of criminal activity going on in London (most surveilled city in the world) and no one is getting caught.  In what year is this supposed to have taken place?

Comment: Not sure what relevance the "most surveilled city" part is .... 9 out of 10 crimes in the UK don't result in a charge being brought by the police and nearly half of all crimes have no identified suspect.  https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-44884113.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_Cake_(novel)?wprov=sfti1 The novel was apparently first published in 2000, with the story set in 1997. Unless the film has a specific reference to a date (not sure from your question whether you’ve watched it?) I’d generally assume that it’s set in ‘Contemporary Britain’, I.e around the year it came out.

Comment: That said, you can look at the number plates for any cars in the film to work out the earliest it could have been too

Comment: @iandotkelly That's a much too narrow reading of "surveilled". It's still surveillance even if the people caught on camera are not easily identifiable. Also, _"9 out of 10 crimes in the UK don't result in a charge being brought by the police"_ is a misrepresentation of facts. If you could prove it was a crime, it's likely to result in a charge. The statistic you're using is likely in regards to reports/complaints that are lodged, which are not necessarily actual crimes - or worth pursuing in court.

Comment: @Flater .... and there are crimes that are not reported and therefore don't appear on any statistics.  My point is that a lot of crime does not result in people getting caught.  Despite the somewhat spurious reasoning that London is highly surveilled.  And yes I know London does not equal the UK.  Plus that 9 out of 10 crimes quote is from Home Office official statistics.  A burglary of a property or a mugging is a crime .... if no-one is identified as a suspect, or if not enough evidence is available that would bring about a conviction in a criminal court there is no charge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the film is set in at least 2003 and the plot wasn't affected much by the 6-year difference between the book and the film just certain things like cars and phones were adapted. Also, bear in mind that the accountant uses a not too ancient looking computer.
Eddie temple's 2003 registration Bentley Arnage:

[image: Eddie temple's Bentley Arnage]

The Range Rover used: I believe this is a 1998 number plate and I can more or less see S628 CRO which uses the S prefix for 1990's registrations.Bear in mind that these are the wannabes and probably just bought an older model of a flashy car to seem more affluent.[image: Number plate guide]
[image: Layer cake range rover]
[image: Bentley release dates]

This phone that looks closer to 2003 type phone than 1997, however, someone may correct me in the comments as I believe a 1997 nokia could have a similar colour and design, however, a lot of phones in 1997 were black.
[image: Layer cake phone]

Comment: The Bentley makes it no earlier than Jan 2003, for absolute certain. Anything else could simply be 'an earlier model' but the Bentley plate nails it to at least then.

Comment: Yes especially since the owners of the range rovers are seen to be the "wannabes" and probably would go for an older model of a flashy car.

Answer (score 0):

The hit man that's learning French, is obviously a big fan of Leon the professional which was released in 1995, so around this time fits well for me.

Comment: That's sort of a stretch... also doesn't prove anything. Check the accepted answer, with much more evidence to back it up.